# How to add sequencial number and rename filename on python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I search and wrote code like this, but dose not work. Please suggest me.
I have huge number of media files what I have downloaded. I want to add serial number to those.
This code dose not work, but even not notice error.
Please help me

```
import os

path = os.getcwd() 
dirc = os.listdir(path)
n = 0

for file in dirc:
    os.chdir(path)
    if file.endswith('*.txt'):
        rename(srt(n) + file, file)
        n += 1
```

Comment: Did you try your code? Edit it to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

path = os.getcwd() 
n = 1

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        src = path + '\\' + filename
        dst = path + '\\' + str(n) + '-' + filename
        os.rename(src, dst)
        n+=1
```

Above code replaces filenames `abcd.txt` with `1-abcd.txt` and so on.

Comment: Please run the code in the directory where files are present. Else you can replace `os.getcwd()` with your directory location and run code from anywhere.